# String Algorithm Comparison VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, algorithm

I would like to ask some suggestions cause I've been doing this for a week.
It's basically a data cleanup program.
I have this excel file which contains thousands of company name and I have this database which contains the correct names of companies. 
What I want is to read the excel file which I already did and compare each of the company in the excel file with the values I have on database. For example

Data in Excel

- Hewlett-Packard, Costa Rica
- Hewlett-Packard (HP)
- Hewlett-Packard Singapore (Private) Limited

Data in Database

- Hewlett-Packard

It will auto detect that those 3 value in excel is Hewlett-Packard because the excel is in free type form. I want to correct everything that is inputted in it and find the similar value in my database. Like if the Hewlett-Packard is spelled wrong it will automatically tell that its Hewlett-Packard. Any idea?

It's like an autocomplete but with thinking. Autocomplete but decides the correct value

I'm doing it in VB.Net btw. I'm researching about fuzzy search algorithim and levenstein and stuff. But I still don't get it how can i use that

Comment: I might just be easier to output all the unique company name that aren't currently in the database and hardcode the link yourself. Might be boring job but it'll be much quicker. If you have a million unique names, that's an other story.

Comment: I got 44946 data in my database and I think that's not all of it

Answer (score 1):

See my blog, [Solving the right problem](http://blog.mischel.com/2014/10/20/solving-the-right-problem/), which is somewhat similar. You're probably better off doing a simple match and outputting any failures to a text file, which you manually edit. It's drudgery, but it'll get the job done. When you start talking about Levenstein distance and fuzzy search, you're turning a simple, if dull, task into a research project.

If your database contains only "thousands" (rather than millions) of names, then one thing you can do is load all the names into a list, and sort them. Then sort the names in the Excel file. Then go through the two lists (a standard merge-type algorithm). For example, you might have in your database:

```
Hasbro
Hewlett Packard
Home Depot
```

and in your Excel file:

```
Grainger
Halliburton
Hewlet Packard, Costa Rica
Hewlett Packard (HP)
Humana
```

Using the merge algorithm, you'd be comparing "Hewlet Packard, Costa Rica" against "Hewlett Packard", and you might even output that as the suggested replacement. That would probably constitute the majority of your errors.

In any case, I strongly recommend using the computer to identify the mismatches, and then *manually* resolve them. That's usually the fastest way to solve this type of problem.

Comment: I guess there's no other way than manually solving the problem after reducing the amount of duplicate and errors in my excel file. Great suggestion Jim! Would try to figure this out rather than research about fuzzy search algorithims